# How to call a UISwitch touch without using IBaction/InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to call a function whenever my UISwitch is tapped without using an @ib action but am having trouble finding the proper way to do this nothing is seeming to work no matter how i try to call it. I am using everything through code and not storyboard so using an ib property isn't really an option i am trying to use at going about this

I am using this but keep getting the error

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
  func gameSwitchTapped(){
    print("touched")
    if gameMuteSwitch.isOn == true {
      gameview.saveData.set(false, forKey: gameview.gameMuteKey)
    } else {
      gameview.saveData.set(true, forKey: gameview.gameMuteKey)}
    }
```

And, elsewhere:

```
  gameMuteSwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("gameSwitchTapped")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Update your question with relevant details/code.

Comment: I've tried using the touch location of the user through touchesBegan to see if i could check whenever the frame of the uiswitch is touched which didn't work  along with many variations of that  through touches began

Comment: I think you want `action: #selector(gameSwitchTapped)`

Comment: that made it work but its strange it works randomly now i have 2 switches in the scene and it only seems to work when i activate one then activate the other and vice versa not when i just activate the one performing the action

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm trying to understand something similar. How did you create the Switch? And how did you get a first reference to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(sender:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
   let value = mySwitch.on
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: im not using objective c but converted it to swift syntax although i keep getting the issue terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: and what does it say?

Comment: when do you get it?

Comment: whenever the switch is tapped although I've moved code around to different locations and it only crashes when both function and action are in did move to view

Comment: it all works now but it works randomly... once the function gets called once it works every time for both switches when they get touched but it takes about 20 clicks or so of messing with them before the function gets called the first time to get it going...

Comment: i figured it out the code was just misplaced once i moved it into viewdidload it worked everytime thanks

Comment: Where does mySwitch come from?

Comment: `mySwitch` is the reference to the `UISwitch` object, you can create it by yourself or assign one from storyboard

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C:

```
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```